# Boost.stacktrace. Как сделать трассировку стека произвольного потока?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, stacktrace, boost-stacktrace

Пытаюсь прикрутить к своему проекту трассировку стека boost.stacktrace. После множества попыток удалось добиться вывода состояния стека основного потока, но при попытке вывести состояние стека другого потока всё равно выводится стек основного.

Kubuntu 18.04; cmake 14.3; GCC 8.3; boost 1.70; IDE Qt Creator 4.9.0.

C++ код:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void my_signal_handler(int signum) {
    ::signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    std::cout << "[ Thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "]" << std::endl << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace() << std::flush << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    ::raise(SIGABRT);
}

void Bar_1(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        volatile int a{5};
        return;
    } else
        Bar_1(i - 1);
}

void Bar_2(int i) {

    if (i == 10) {
        volatile int a{5};
        return;
    } else
        Bar_2(i + 1);
}
int main() {
//    ::signal(SIGSEGV, &my_signal_handler);
//    ::signal(SIGABRT, &my_signal_handler);
//    ::signal(SIGKILL, &my_signal_handler);
//    ::signal(SIGSTOP, &my_signal_handler);
//    ::signal(SIGTERM, &my_signal_handler);

    std::thread th([]() {
        ::signal(SIGSEGV, &my_signal_handler);
        ::signal(SIGABRT, &my_signal_handler);
        ::signal(SIGKILL, &my_signal_handler);
        ::signal(SIGSTOP, &my_signal_handler);
        ::signal(SIGTERM, &my_signal_handler);
        while (true) {
            Bar_2(1);
        }
    });
    th.detach();
    while (true) {
        Bar_1(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Консольный вывод:

```
[ Thread: 139926248552256]
0# my_signal_handler(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:12
1# 0x00007F431E742100 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
2# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:23
3# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:24
4# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:24
5# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:24
6# main at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:53
7# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
8# _start in /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled6

[ Thread: 139926248552256]
0# my_signal_handler(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:12
1# 0x00007F431E742100 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
2# raise in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
3# my_signal_handler(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:16
4# 0x00007F431E742100 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
5# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:23
6# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:24
7# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:24
8# Bar_1(int) at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:24
9# main at /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/untitled6/main.cpp:53
10# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
11# _start in /home/rivandblack/MainProjects/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled6
```

CMake скрипт:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14.3)

project (untitled6)

add_definitions (-DBOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                 "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -lstdc++fs")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG           "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -lstdc++fs -g -DDREAL_DEBUG -DDREAL_TRACE -fno-inline")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL      "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -lstdc++fs -Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -lstdc++fs -O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -lstdc++fs -O2 -g")

# Подключаем boost.
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)      # Определяем в каком режиме будет работать boost в статическом или динамическом
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)   # Будет ли boost работать в многопоточном режиме.
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)      
BOOST_ROOT (system тут обязательна)
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})   
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})                
#------------ Подключение Backtrace -------------------
find_package(Backtrace REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set (Backtrace_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/lib/libbacktrace.a")
#-----------------------------------------------------

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    "main.cpp"
    )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}   ${Backtrace_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь произвести трассировку стека из обработчика асинхронного сигнала. Такие сигналы выполняются отдельно от потоков, а вызов функций, не присутствующих в перечне [async signal safe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_02) является неопределенным поведением. Соответственно трасировку необходимо вызывать непосредственно из кода, выполняющего в интересующем потоке.

Comment: Спасибо. Но как мне тогда быть если мне необходимо узнать состояние стека всех потоков во время прихода сигфола (мне нужно отловить сигфол в большом проекте =))?

Comment: @mrFieldy Включите создание дампов. А потом производите постмортем анализ. Ни обработчики сигналов, ни boost для этого не нужны.

Comment: можно поподробнее, что за дампы?

Comment: @mrFieldy ну core dumps, ака корки см https://linux-audit.com/understand-and-configure-core-dumps-work-on-linux/

Comment: спасибо большое, ушёл читать.